# Module name in the export table of a PE image

Tags: windows, pe

One of the fields of the PE export table is the image name, see screenshot below for an example.

This name is part of the file, even though I can rename it to any other name after it's compiled.

My questions:

- Why is it needed?
- When is this name used?
- What are the implications of this name and the file name going out of sync? Does it matter?

[image: example export table]

Comment: "Why is it needed?" -- What alternative did you think of?

Comment: Alternatives for what? Just use the dll file name?

Comment: It does not matter if the value is not correct. You can rename a DLL on disk and it will still load regardless of this value. This is often seen in malware. As for the real use: I have not found one yet.